# app.config is not renamed while deploying TFS build

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, msbuild, tfsbuild

The `app.config` file is usually renamed to something like `yourAppName.exe.config` during the build. I have a solution deployed to a server using a usual TFS build. Once I run the application, I see an exception in the first invocation of `ConfigurationManager`. Logging on the server and checking the files, I saw that the `app.config` was not renamed and this was causing the exception. After renaming the file, the application is working properly.

Thus, I'm wondering why the file is not renamed and if this can be fixed somehow.

UPD: `app.config` file has `Build Action` set to `None` and `Copy to Output Directory` set to `Do not copy`.

Comment: How do you do deployment from your TFSBuild? Sounds like youre taking sources rather than compiled binaries. Show some relevant MSBuild maybe?

Comment: Don't really understand what do you mean. Here are the arguments passed to MSBuild in the TFSBuild Process configuration: `/p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:Configuration=Debug /p:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish /p:MSDeployPublishMethod=RemoteAgent /p:MsDeployServiceUrl=server /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True /p:username=Administrator /p:password=password`

And you are right about the source rather than compiled binaries. The build is done on a remote machine which gets the latest version from TFS, builds it and deploys to the specified server.

Comment: Can you set MSBUILD Arugument to Publish. e.g. /t:publish. It may start publishing the application.

Comment: I had this happen today with publishing a console application in Visual Studio 2013 when I renamed the Assembly under the "Application" tab of the project properties. Prior to that `App.config` was getting renamed to `[assembly].exe.config` and now it remains `App.config` after publishing. I'm still trying to root out the cause.